# BrowseTo MacroAction Won't Accept User Input for Where Clause

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to make a BrowseTo action in MS Access 2016 accept user input in a where clause. The input comes from a textbox called searchText. It can be seen [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWilm.png)

I've tried before and have had no luck. When I click the button it returns a blank.

Comment: @June7 can you help?

Comment: Nothing in the WHERE CONDITION argument so nothing to analyze. Advise not to use popup inputs - cannot validate user input. Use a form for input and parameter references control on form. I don't use macros, only VBA. I have never used BrowseTo. There are several methods in VBA to filter or go to record.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do? Use combobox in subform to filter subform? I am testing this macro and really not liking. I would have switched to VBA by now.

Comment: Are you using a normal form/subform or is this a Navigation form? I never use Navigation form.

Comment: Its a subform within a navigation form. The thing is that I dont know VBA

Comment: Try: `[OutletName] LIKE '*' & [SearchText] & '*'` or `[OutletName] = [SearchText]`. Both work for me.

Comment: Thanks @June7, problem solved.